# SpringBoot + Mybatis + MySQL, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, mybatis

I am very new to Spring. I am using SpringBoot + Mybatis + MySQL, I have this exception when I did my Unit test for my UserDAO : "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext". I follow this link to setting up my testing environment: http://www.mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-test-autoconfigure/. I have searched a lot, but still can't find a solution. Could someone give me some advice? Thanks a lot in advance :)

Here is my Mybatis config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE configuration
    PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
    "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
```

```
<settings>
    <!-- Globally enables or disables any caches configured in any mapper under this configuration -->
    <setting name="cacheEnabled" value="true"/>
    <!-- Sets the number of seconds the driver will wait for a response from the database -->
    <setting name="defaultStatementTimeout" value="3000"/>
    <!-- Enables automatic mapping from classic database column names A_COLUMN to camel case classic Java property names aColumn -->
    <setting name="mapUnderscoreToCamelCase" value="true"/>
    <!-- Allows JDBC support for generated keys. A compatible driver is required.
    This setting forces generated keys to be used if set to true,
     as some drivers deny compatibility but still work -->
    <setting name="useGeneratedKeys" value="true"/>
</settings>

<!-- Continue going here --> 
</configuration>
```

Here is my pom.file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.jingjie</groupId>
<artifactId>forum_demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>forum_demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    -->

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And here is my UserDao

```
@Mapper
public interface UserDao {

    static final String USER_TABLE = "user";
    final String INSERT_FIELDS = " name, password, salt, head_url";
    final String SELECT_FIELDS = " id, name, password, salt, head_url";

    // insert a record into user table
    @Insert({"Insert into ", USER_TABLE, " (" + INSERT_FIELDS + ") values " +
        "(#{name}, #{password}, #{salt}, #{headUrl})"})
    void addUser(User user);

    // select a record according to a given user id
    @Select({"select ", SELECT_FIELDS, " from ", USER_TABLE, " where id = #
{id}"})
    User getUserViaId(int id);

    // select a record according to a given user name
    @Select({"select ", SELECT_FIELDS , " from ", USER_TABLE, " where name = #
{name}"})
    User getUserViaName(String name);

    // update a user's password accroding to a given user id
    @Update({"update ", USER_TABLE, " set password = #{password} where id = #
{id}"})
    void updatePassword(int id);

    // delete a record accroding to a given user id
    @Delete({"delete from ", USER_TABLE, " where id = #{id]"})
    void deleteRecordViaId(int id);
}
```

Here is my applications.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/forum_demo?
useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8&amp;useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=*****
mybatis.config-location=classpath:src/main/resources/mybatis-config.xml
```

Here is my Test class:

```
package com.jingjie.forum_demo.daotest;

import com.jingjie.forum_demo.dao.UserDao;
import com.jingjie.forum_demo.model.User;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mybatis.spring.boot.test.autoconfigure.MybatisTest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import java.util.Random;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
//@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@MybatisTest
//@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace= AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Rplace.NONE)
//@Sql("/forum_demo.sql")
public class UserDaoTest {

    @Autowired
    UserDao userDaoTest;

    @Test
    public void addUserTest() {

        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i ++) {
            // perform some test
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the testing fail info:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.jingjie.forum_demo.daotest.UserDaoTest]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to read meta-data for class org.mybatis.spring.boot.autoconfigure.MybatisAutoConfiguration
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:556)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:185)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:308)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:272)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:92)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to read meta-data for class org.mybatis.spring.boot.autoconfigure.MybatisAutoConfiguration
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter$AutoConfigurationClass.getAnnotationMetadata(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:217)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter$AutoConfigurationClass.getAnnotationValue(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:198)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter$AutoConfigurationClass.readBefore(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:186)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter$AutoConfigurationClass.<init>(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:158)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter$AutoConfigurationClasses.<init>(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:115)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter.getInPriorityOrder(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:57)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.sort(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:241)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.selectImports(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:98)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:547)
... 38 more 
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50)
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:98)
at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:89)
at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:93)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter$AutoConfigurationClass.getAnnotationMetadata(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:213)
... 46 more
Process finished with exit code 255
```

Comment: It cannot find the MybatisAutoConfiguration class.

Comment: Yes, I can tell from the error, but I have searched on Google, it rarely mentions this class. It seems to me that it is a class that Mybatis should manage by itself?? Not sure...

Comment: Could be that's the case http://www.mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-test-autoconfigure/

Comment: Exactly, at the end of the  link, it says the class should be imported automatically when I used @MybatisTest...I am really stuck here

Comment: It's stated in the end that you need to define onw Spring App to avoid using default one. Have you tried?

Comment: Did you mean to create a "@SpringBootApplication" class? sorry to ask again, I am really new to Spring :P

Comment: Hi, I did add a SpringBootApplication to the package that owns the test class, as the link instructed. But it still shows the same error.                                 public class TestingApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestingApplication.class, args);
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem, I used the wrong package for Mybatis in pom.file. That is why due to the code is correct, but it shows such an error